# Can't connect to MongoDB Atlas database from Node server on cPanel

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, cpanel

I deployed a node server on cPanel, which is connected to a MongoDB Atlas database.

I added my local IP address and the IP address which have been gave to me by my hosting provider to the mongoDB Cluster whitelist, but i still can't connect my node server to my database.

Each time i try to (try to log in my front app, or register a new user), I have this error message in logs :
"*Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: [https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist*/"](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist*/%22) or i could have this error message too :
"*error dans catch Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms*" but it seems that it is related to the same issue...

My server.js file :

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const multer = require('multer');
require('dotenv').config();

const pets = require('./routes/api/pet');
const users = require('./routes/api/user');
const weight = require('./routes/api/weight');
const vaccine = require('./routes/api/vaccine');
const deworming = require('./routes/api/deworming');
const antiflea = require('./routes/api/antiflea');
const events = require('./routes/api/event');

const app = express();

// bodyparser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const corsOptions = {
  origin: ['http://********'],
  allowedHeaders: [
    'Accept',
    'Origin',
    'Content-Type',
    'Authorization',
    'X-requested-Width',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
    'Access-Control-Request-Headers',
  ],
  credentials: true,
  enablePreflight: true,
};

// cors manage
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// cookie-parser middleware
app.use(cookieParser());

// use routes
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send(`
    <div style="margin: 5em auto; font-family: Roboto">
        <p>Serveur lancé sur ${process.env.HOST}/${process.env.PORT}</p>
    </div>`)
})
app.use('/upload/avatars', express.static(__dirname + '/upload/avatars'));
app.use('/api/pet', pets);
app.use('/api/user', users);
app.use('/api/pet/weight', weight);
app.use('/api/pet/vaccine', vaccine);
app.use('/api/pet/deworming', deworming);
app.use('/api/pet/antiflea', antiflea);
app.use('/api/event', events);

// errors handling middleware
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.log(err.stack);
  res.status(500).send({message: 'Une erreur est survenue !'});
})

// Connect to Mongo
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI,
    { useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true})
  .then(() => console.log('Connexion avec MongoDB réussie !'))
  .catch(err => {
      console.log('Il doit y avoir un souci avec la database MongoDB Atlas')
      console.log(err)
  });

app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.HOST, () => console.log(`Serveur lancé sur le port ${process.env.PORT}`));
```

When I start my node server with localhost, the connexion with my mongoDB db work fine, so I don't really understand why it's not working with my production server.

And my MONGO_URI is as below :
mongodb+srv://:@cluster0.eg3tx.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority

I already tried several solutions but no one worked for me. Anyone has an idea ?

Comment: Did you open port 27017 on the firewall of your host?

Comment: My bad, I forgot to answer and close this issue !
Your solution was the good one :)
I thought that my provider had already opened the port but it wasn't done. 
I opened it myself and it's ok !